# Matching multiple lines in two patterns regex

Tags: java, regex

I need find some solution and cannot find it. It looks like the solution is quite close, but something is missing and I believe you can help me with it.

That's the string and each line is one string:

```
Pinging www.onet.pl [52.85.243.125] with 64 bytes of data [Type=8 Code=0] [TTL=255]:
Reply from: 52.85.243.125:0 seq=1 bytes=92 type=ECHO REPLY time=12,7ms
Reply from: 52.85.243.125:0 seq=2 bytes=92 type=ECHO REPLY time=11,3ms
Reply from: 52.85.243.125:0 seq=3 bytes=92 type=ECHO REPLY time=13,1ms
Reply from: 52.85.243.125:0 seq=4 bytes=92 type=ECHO REPLY time=13,2ms
```

and my code:

```java
String REGEX_1 = "\\A.*\\[TTL=(\\d+)\\]:$";
String REGEX_2 = ".*Reply from.*seq=(\\d+).*time=(\\d+).*";

List<Pattern> patterns = new ArrayList<>();
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_1);
        final Pattern pattern_2 = Pattern.compile(REGEX_2, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        patterns.add(pattern);
        patterns.add(pattern_2);
        for(Pattern pat : patterns){
            final Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(string);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                try {
                    final int ttl = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                    final long seq = Long.parseLong(matcher.group(2));
                    final double rtt = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(3));
                    return new Statistics(rtt, ttl, seq);
                } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

What I want to do is to fetch `TTL` from the first string and `seq`/`time` from next ones.

The expected output is:

```
time=12,7, TTL=255, seq=1
time=11,3, TTL=255, seq=2
time=13,1, TTL=255, seq=3
time=13,2, TTL=255, seq=4
```

Previously I had only one pattern, but it didn't work as well, so I was told to split it up. Unfortunately, I cannot find the solution. As it is above, it doesn't return anything. Could you please help me?

I have tried to put

```java
while(matcher.find())
```

inside the if condition, but didn't work out neither.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: I want to match TTL, seq and RTT from the string I posted above.

Comment: You want to extract values for those parameters?

Comment: Yes, that's I want to do.

Comment: Are all the input lines (5 lines in your example) one string, or 5 separate strings?

Comment: 5 separate strings, but it might be much more as it is printout from PowerPing application.

Comment: I posted answer. I assumed it will be only one string. Since you are getting multiple strings, you can just apply regex on any string you want. Since I don't really know your code setup and how those strings will come to you, I can't really modify my answer according to that. Basically, you have regexes and way to apply them to strings, so you can modify it according to your needs... or you can specify what more is needed to be done.

Comment: @Chris - It's improved. I replaced `final` with `expected` in your edited question. I hope my edit is correct. If not, you can revert my edit to the last version.

Comment: @Chris - Does [this solution](https://ideone.com/PNeNnR) work for you?

Comment: I am troubleshooting it, because the printout is strange(but it's better).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try something like this:

```
ttl regex -> "TTL=(\\d+)"
seq regex -> "seq=(\\d+)"
time regex -> "time=(\\d+,\\d+)ms"
```

If we assume that your whole example is only one string, you can do it like this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Pinging www.onet.pl [52.85.243.125] with 64 bytes of data [Type=8 Code=0] [TTL=255]:\n" +
                       "Reply from: 52.85.243.125:0 seq=1 bytes=92 type=ECHO REPLY time=12,7ms\n" +
                       "Reply from: 52.85.243.125:0 seq=2 bytes=92 type=ECHO REPLY time=11,3ms\n" +
                       "Reply from: 52.85.243.125:0 seq=3 bytes=92 type=ECHO REPLY time=13,1ms\n" +
                       "Reply from: 52.85.243.125:0 seq=4 bytes=92 type=ECHO REPLY time=13,2ms";

        // Regex pattern for TTL
        Pattern ttlPattern = Pattern.compile("TTL=(\\d+)");
        Matcher ttlMatcher = ttlPattern.matcher(input);
        if (ttlMatcher.find()) {
            String ttl = ttlMatcher.group(1);
            System.out.println("TTL: " + ttl);
        }

        // Regex pattern for seq
        Pattern seqPattern = Pattern.compile("seq=(\\d+)");
        Matcher seqMatcher = seqPattern.matcher(input);
        while (seqMatcher.find()) {
            String seq = seqMatcher.group(1);
            System.out.println("Seq: " + seq);
        }

        // Regex pattern for time
        Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("time=(\\d+,\\d+)ms");
        Matcher timeMatcher = timePattern.matcher(input);
        while (timeMatcher.find()) {
            String time = timeMatcher.group(1);
            System.out.println("Time: " + time);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is gonna be:

```
TTL: 255
Seq: 1
Seq: 2
Seq: 3
Seq: 4
Time: 12,7
Time: 11,3
Time: 13,1
Time: 13,2
```

In case that you have multiple lines (strings), you can just apply specific regex on specific line that you want. I intentionally separated regexes and it's applying so it can be easily modified.